# Use value as key for another object in jq

Tags: json, bash, jq

I setup a json config file like this

```
{
    "current": "config1",
    "config1": {
        "p1": "val1-1",
        "p2": "val1-2"
    },
    "config2": {
        "p1": "val2-1",
        "p2": "val2-2"
    }
}
```

I would like to get "current" config with bash and jq.
At the moment I use:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

C=`jq '.current' $1`
D=`eval jq '."$C"' $1`
echo " ------  D is $D"
echo $D | jq  '.p1'
```

Is there a direct jq filter/key trick to obtain the same result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to use the `.[]` [object value iterator](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Array/ObjectValueIterator:.%5B%5D) syntax to first let `.current` expand to its constituent value and then the expression becomes `."config1"` which matches the `config1` key

```
jq '.[.current]'
```